# Confirm record deletion without a click php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a navigation menu that I like to use because it makes navigating fast and easy:

```
<form action="../">
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
<option value="" selected="selected">Navigate</option>

<option value="view_record.php?file_id=<? echo $row['file_id']; ?>">View</option>
<option value="delete_record.php?file_id=<? echo $row['file_id']; ?>" >Delete</option>

</select>
</form>
```

Both onchange navigations hit their respective .php pages, no problem.

But to delete a record, the way it is, once the user hits that selection on the navigation menu, they are toast, esp if they inadvertently select it.

I have tried several things to somehow modify the onclick javascript thing:

```
echo "<td><a onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href='delete.php?id=".$query2['id']."'>DELETE</a></td><tr>";
```

which works if you click 'DELETE', but in my navigation menu, it is an onchange event.

I tried this:

```
<form action="../">
<select onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">
 <option value="" selected="selected">Navigate</option>

<option value="view_record.php?file_id=<? echo $row['file_id']; ?>">View</option>


</select>
</form>

<form action="../">
<select onchange="javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');">
<option value="" selected="selected">Navigate</option>

<option value="delete_f.php?file_id=<? echo $row['file_id']; ?>" >Delete Case </option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

But all that does is stacks two menus on top of each other.

I was looking for a way to have some sort of conditional statement to change the onchange event based on the link, but the link is underneath the 'select onchange' command, which means it gets read first.

I tried to add code to the awaiting php page to pop up a confirm delete alert box, but all I ended up with was a box with an 'OK' and not a 'OK' and 'Cancel' to return to the former page if canceled.

EDIT

I tried adding this to the php page:

```
echo '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">';
echo 'var checK = confirm("Are you sure to delete?")';
echo 'if (!checK)';
echo '{';
echo 'history.go(-1); ';
echo '}';

echo '</script>';
```

but nothing happens

I tried this:

```
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'confirm("message successfully sent")';
echo '</script>';
```

but when I click cancel, there is no return to the previous page. I don't know how to get php to recognize the user clicked cancel to then navigate back. Plus, even if I click Cancel, the rest of the php code just runs.

Comment: protip: *never* put JS inline. Need an onchange handler? `<select onchange="handleChange(this)">` and then have a real JS `function handleChange(select) { ... }` that checks what the user selected, so it can do filtering when necessary. And don't `echo` it in, just write it in a .js file and `<script src="thatfile.js">` it into your page. There are a lot more things you can improve here, but that's for http://codereview.stackexchange.com to comment on.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you'll actually need to call the JavaScript function. As much as we'd all like, Javascript (as well as any other language) acts on a trigger. Try something like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConfirmDelete()
{
var IsOkToDelete = Confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
if (IsOkToDelete) { // not sure how you're doing the delete but it happens here

// Once you delete it you can use window.location.href = 'http://mywebsite.com/records' or something url there --- EDIT: actually you can use window.history.back() as well if you want to go back one page programatically.
} 
// else the function falls through and no navigation/deletion happens happens.
}
</script>
```

Then you actually call the script like so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="ConfirmDelete()" value="Go" />
```

Comment: As stated above by fellow S/O user Mike, it's always good practice to segregate code, especially if in different languages as not to clutter the page and make it easy to edit for yourself and others in the future. I would endorse his recommendation of putting it in a .js file and calling it as <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywebserver.com/scripts/confirm.js"/> and then calling the function as stated above in my answer. @Mike, never hurts to give pointers where we can :)

Answer (score 1):

As the fellow users are suggesting, you should avoid using the JS inline or mix the PHP with javascript. The code you are trying above should look like this.

Your form code

```
<form action="../">
<select onchange="redirectFunc(this.value,'<? echo $row['file_id']; ?>')">
<option value="" selected="selected">Navigate</option>

<option value="view">View</option>
<option value="delete" >Delete</option>

</select>
</form>
```

And then your script

```
<script>
function redirectFunc(action,id){
    if(action!=""){
    if(action=='view'){
        var url='view_record.php?file_id='+id;
        window.open(url,'_top')
    }else{
        var conf=confirm('Are you sure to delete this record');
        if(conf){
            var url='delete_record.php?file_id='+id;
            location.href=url;
        }
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

This way you can dynamically use the JS function without using it inline or without repeating it in a loop.

Comment: They say not to say thank you, but since my reputation is just a 6 I can't give you credit. I never would have thought up this code and it is perfect for the task, clean and efficient.

Comment: @user6096423 If this solves your problem, you can accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="../">
  <select onchange="decideWhatToDo(this.value, this.selectedIndex, this)">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Navigate</option>

    <option value="view_record.php?file_id=<? echo $row['file_id']; ?>">View</option>
    <option value="delete_record.php?file_id=<? echo $row['file_id']; ?>" >Delete</option>

  </select>
</form>

<script>
function decideWhatToDo(value, index, elem){

var txt = elem.options[index].text

if(txt == 'Delete'){
    if(confirm('Please confirm deletion')){
      // do where to go
   }
  return false;
}
}else{
    //........
//window.open(value,'_top')
}

</script>
```